# Efficient solution to codingBat riddle starOut in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

The problem I am talking about is [this](http://codingbat.com/prob/p139564)

**Problem statment:**

Return a version of the given string, where for every star (*) in the string the star and the chars immediately to its left and right are gone. So "ab*cd" yields "ad" and "ab**cd" also yields "ad".

starOut("ab*cd") → "ad"

starOut("ab**cd") → "ad"

starOut("sm*eilly") → "silly"

The solution I got was a little messy I have used about 6 if statements and a handling for one particular case, looking for cleaner solutions with lesser ifs.

Please do not use more than 1 loop and collections or regex.

Below is my solution:

```java
public String starOut(String str) {
  String result="";
  boolean currentFlag=false;
  
  if(str.length()==0)
  return result;
  
  for(int i=0;i+1<str.length();i++)
  {
    if(str.charAt(i)=='*')
    {
       i+=1;
       currentFlag=true;
       continue;
     }
     if(str.charAt(i+1)=='*')
     {
        i+=2;
        continue;
     }
     if((i>0)&&str.charAt(i-1)=='*')
     {
        continue;
     }
     result+=str.substring(i,i+1);
     currentFlag=false;

   }
   
  if(!(currentFlag)&&(str.length()==3)&&(str.charAt(1)=='*'))
      return ""; 
      
   if((str.charAt(str.length()-1)!='*')&!(currentFlag))
     return result+=str.charAt(str.length()-1);
    else
      return result;
}
```

Comment: You should check out [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: Thanks I do know regex but do not wish to solve it using regex.

Comment: Also, if you have working code, I'd suggest you take this over to [CodeReview SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You can flag this yourself to let a mod know if you want this migrated.

Comment: No offense Anirudh, but it looks like regex might be a step too far judging on your code. Don't try to look ahead in your loop; that's what the loop's for. Start at the first char, check it, handle special cases, make changes, move on.

Comment: Please post a solution instead of ranting about regex. It's nowhere mentioned in the question to involve regex. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about review the code of a solution. The question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Pseudocode:**

Step through all the characters in the string.  If you land on an asterisk, don't record it.  Peek left, and if you see an asterisk, don't record it.  Peek right if you see an asterisk, don't record it.  If none of the above things happen, record it.

**Java code:**

```
public static String starOut(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == '*') continue;
        if (i > 0 && s.charAt(i - 1) == '*') continue;
        if (i < s.length() - 1 && s.charAt(i + 1) == '*') continue;
            
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

---

<sup>**Note:** I see a lot of answers pop up that are concatenating `String` objects in the loop instead of using a `StringBuilder`. Don't do that. It's [very inefficient](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1643).</sup>

Comment: Very neat sir but in place of stringbuilder you could simply use String as well.

Comment: And that would be better why?

Comment: @Anirudh `StringBuilder` has its usage exactly in that type of - uhm - _string building_ inside a loop.

Comment: @Anirudh Why would the StringBuilder need to be thread-safe in this case? There is zero possibility for multiple threads to simultaneously access this StringBuilder. Otherwise I would have used a StringBuffer.

Comment: StringBuilder is def the way to go for efficient concatenation in strings. Should have included it, but I was trying to keep mine as basic as possible considering the no regex/collection 1 loop constraint.

Comment: @DaveS `charAt()` results in a direct access to the string's underlying character array. Even so, assigning it to a variable would eliminate some function calls and probably make things slightly faster. Same goes for the call to the string's `length()` method.

Comment: Thanks Robby deleted my question because I googled it and found it to be O(1) but the constant reduction may be worth the memory.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution I wrote. It uses 1 loop.

```
public String starOut(String str)
{
    String ret = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {        
        if (!( '*' == str.charAt(i) 
        || i + 1 < str.length() && '*' == str.charAt(i+1)
        || i > 0 && '*' == str.charAt(i-1) ))
        {
            ret = ret + str.charAt(i);
        }        
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Splendid!! Very well crafted and looks elegant too.

Answer (score 2):

I thought it would be simple to use regex and pattern matching for this problem

```
public String starOut(String str) {
  String pattern = "([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,1})\\*+([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,1})";
  str = str.replaceAll(pattern, "");
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with

```
public String starOut(String str)
{
  boolean lastIsStar = false;
  String result = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
  {
     char c = str.charAt(i);
     if(lastIsStar)
     {
        if(c != '*')
        {
            lastIsStar = false;
        }
     }
     else if(c == '*')
     {
        lastIsStar = true;
        if(i-1 > -1)
        {
           result = result.substring(0, result.length()-1);
        }
     }
     else
     {
        result += c;
        lastIsStar = false;
     }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: That's surely a better one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After an hour wrote this... still don't like it

```
String result = "";
boolean toDelete = false;
boolean deleted = true;

for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++){
   if (str.charAt(i) != '*'){
       if(toDelete == false) result += str.charAt(i);
       toDelete = false;
       deleted = false;
       continue;
   }
   if(deleted == false){
      result = result.substring(0,result.length()-1);
      deleted = true;
   }

   toDelete = true;      
}

return result.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and effective. The if's can be combined with || but this looks cleaner.

```
public String starOut(String str) {

  int i = 0 ;
  for (int i = 0; i <str.length(); i++) {

    if (str.charAt(i) == '*') continue;
    if (i+1<str.length() && str.charAt(i+1) =='*') continue;
    if (i>0 && str.charAt(i-1) !='*') continue;
    ret += str.charAt(i);
  }  
  return ret;  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly modified code based on Andrew's answer:

```
public String starOut(String str) {
    String pattern = "([^*]{0,1})\\*+([^*]{0,1})";
    return str.replaceAll(pattern, "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution -

```
  public String starOut(String str) {
boolean prevWasStar = false;
String ans = "";
for (int i=0; i<str.length();i++){
  int l = ans.length();
    if (str.charAt(i)=='*'){
        if (!prevWasStar){
          if(i==0) l = l+1;
            ans=ans.substring(0, l-1);
        } 
        prevWasStar=true;
} else{
  if(!prevWasStar) ans = ans + str.charAt(i);
  prevWasStar = false;
}
}return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
public String starOut(String str) {
  String result = "";
  for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    if (!(str.substring(Math.max(0, i-1), Math.min(str.length(), i+2)).contains("*"))) result += str.charAt(i);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this post is too old and already has many good answers and since I invested so much time behind this exercise, I would also like to contribute by providing my answer on this.

```
public String starOut(String str) 
{
  String b = "";
  if(str.length() == 1 && !str.equals("*"))
  {
    b = str;
  }
  for(int i=0; i<str.length()-1;i++)
  {
     if(str.charAt(i) != '*' && str.charAt(i+1) != '*')
     {
        b = b + str.charAt(i);
     }
     if(str.charAt(i) == '*' && str.charAt(i+1) != '*')
     {
        i = i+1;
     }
  }
  if(str.length() > 1 && str.charAt(str.length()-2) != '*' && str.charAt(str.length()-1) != '*')
  {
    b = b + str.substring(str.length()-1);
  }
  return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String starOut(String str)
{
  String ret = "";
  int i;

  if (str.length() == 0 || str.equals("*")) return "";

  for (i = 0; str.charAt(i) == '*'; ++i)
    ;
  if (i > 0 && str.charAt(i-1) == '*')
    ++i;
  while (i < str.length()) {
    if (i == str.length()-1 || i < str.length()-1 && str.charAt(i+1) != '*')
      ret += str.charAt(i++);
    else {
      ++i;
      while (i < str.length() && str.charAt(i) == '*')
        ++i;
      ++i;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution...

```
public String starOut(String str) {
  String result = "";
  int i = 0;
  
  while(i<str.length()){
    if(i==0 && str.charAt(i)!='*') result = result + str.charAt(i);
    
    if(i>0 && str.charAt(i-1)!='*' && str.charAt(i)!='*'){
      result = result + str.charAt(i);
    } 
    if(i>0 && str.charAt(i)=='*' && str.charAt(i-1)!='*'){
      result = result.substring(0, result.length()-1);
    }

    i++;
  }
  
  return result;
  
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, it would help if you add a description to the code you have added.

Answer (score 0):

If you inverse the conditional check first then you can reduce code lines.

```
public static String starOut(String str) {
    String answer = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (!((i > 0 && str.charAt(i - 1) == '*') ||
                (str.charAt(i) == '*') ||
                (i < str.length() - 1 && str.charAt(i + 1) == '*'))) {
            answer += str.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regular expression in your startOut method to accomplish the requirements.

```
public static String starOut(String str) {
   return str.replaceAll ( ".?[/*]+.?", "");
}
```

Explanation of regular expression:

The `.?`  at the beginning and end of the expression match any single character (or no character in case it's at the beginning or end of a line).  The `[/*]+` in the middle of the expression matches one or more stars.